# How can I add a date range and show by day/week/month to admin grid header?

Tags: admin, grid, magento-community

How can I add some filters to the header of an admin grid? In particular
date range (from - to) and show by day/week/month?

I already looked into a simple extension ([Advanced Report extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advance-report-extension.html)) which is providing this functionality, but for some reason I can't track it down. Any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: In default magento available this type functionality. Check admin site Reports -> Products -> Bestsellers . You are create same way in your custom module.